# Riddle: An impressive thing

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This riddle isn't very difficult but hopefully can you enjoy the rhymes.

> My home is amazing, you might be impressed
>
> I am full of strength, with no time to rest
>
> Everyday I go venture to complete my own quest.
>
> I am one on a team and we all do our best.
>
> To protect my own mother, my life I'll invest.
>
> But sometimes people think we are quite a pest!

What could I be?

Hint:

> Follow the leader is my favorite game

Your answer should match every line, and if possible try to be as specific as possible for the answer.

---

*If you enjoyed this riddle, some of my other rhyming riddles can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brhyme%5D%20user%3A11244%20is%3Aquestion)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a:

> Worker ant

My home is amazing, your might be impressed

> Ant hives are amazingly complex structures, so much that we buy ant farms to see them.

I am full of strength, with no time to rest

> Ants can lift items much heavier than them, and they are always working.

Everyday I go venture to complete my own quest.

> Ants go out every day looking for food, supplies, etc.

I am one on a team and we all do our best.

> Lots of ants in a hive.

To protect my own mother, my life I'll invest.

> They'll sacrifice for the queen.

But Sometime people think we are quite a pest!

> I have ants in my house, and I hate them! (when they are inside)

Hint:

> Worker ants follow each other in a long line. (See the beginning of *A Bugs Life*)

Comment: beat me to it, fairly straigth forward not really an explanation to it.

Comment: Ninja'd again!!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> <s>a bee?</s> an ant?

*My home is amazing, your might be impressed*

> <s>Beehives</s> Anthills have amazing <s>geometric</s> structure.

*I am full of strength, with no time to rest*

> <s>Bees</s> Ants are always <s>buzzing around</s> busy.

*Everyday I go venture to complete my own quest.*

> They go out to <s>get nectar/pollen and bring it home</s> do whatever it is ants do so busily.

*I am one on a team and we all do our best.*

> <s>Bees</s> Ants are social animals.

*To protect my own mother, my life I'll invest.*

> The hive is centred on the queen <s>bee</s> ant, who is mother to many of the others.

*But Sometime people think we are quite a pest!*

> Many people don't like <s>bees</s> ants.

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> termite

My home is amazing, you might be impressed

> Termites can live in human houses.  Quite an impressive home indeed. :)

I am full of strength, with no time to rest

> Termites have very strong jaws and can chew through a lot of materials.

Everyday I go venture to complete my own quest.

> Every day they go look for food and build their nest.

I am one on a team and we all do our best.

> They work collectively to accomplish their goals.

To protect my own mother, my life I'll invest.

> Like with some other insects, they'll die to protect the queen.

But sometimes people think we are quite a pest!

> Termites will cause significant damage to the wood in houses.